# How many jobs,stages , tasks will be created here in this snippet of code of PySpark and Why

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

i have this code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1=spark.read.option('header','true').csv('/FileStore/tables/ds_salaries.csv')\
                                   `enter code here`.withColumn('salary',col('salary').cast('int'))

df1=df1.filter(col('salary')>30000)
df1=df1.groupBy('work_year').agg(sum('salary').alias('total_salary'))
display(df1)
```

When i execute this code , i can see jobs:3, but there are only 2 actions here which are read and display(), so why there is an extra job and whats its for .Am using databricks community edition where its single node and its default configs.

Comment: I think it is because of the reading of the csv. Spark creats a job to be able to get the schema of the csv. If you would provide the schema as an option, it should be only one job.

Comment: i didnot give any inferSchema  ,then why its giving an extra job ?

Comment: Read is not an action

Answer (score 1):

`spark.read` is eagerly evaluated since it needs to find the number of columns & name of columns `('header', 'true')`. Internally it is similar to `df.limit(1).collect()`. So the first job that you see is for the job that reads the first row.

The second job is triggered for the display(df).

Note:

- If you set `inferSchema = true`, you will see one more job, this job will be for finding the datatype of each column, for which spark has to read the file.
- If you supply the schema then it will only have one job for the `display(df)`.
- If you give pattern (glob) spark.read.csv("/parent/folder/") then you will see one job `Listing leaf files...`